# Weka CSVLoader wrong number of values. Read 13, expected 12, read Token[EOL], line 3

Tags: csv, weka

Getting this message when trying to load my csv file in weka.

Here are the lines

```
Random,Session,Id,Indication,Diabetes,IHD,Hypertension,Arrhythmia,History,IPSI,Contra,Risk,
0.621988609,1265,138389,CVA,no,null,no,no,no,99,30,Low,
0.361080211,96760,78604,A-F,no,yes,no,no,no,76,60,Low,
0.998628378,2263,169741,CVA,no,yes,yes,no,no,85,15,Low,
0.302084892,86315,35649,CVA,no,yes,yes,no,no,70 ,100 ,High,
0.348558279,69485,169231,ASx,no,no,yes,no,no,90 ,80 ,High,
0.787705463,54998,64809,TIA,no,no,no,no,no,68 ,30 ,Low,
0.335613554,36654,31473,A-F,no,yes,yes,yes,no,80 ,35 ,High,
0.723987246,67367,97305,TIA,no,no,yes,no,no,81 ,20 ,Low,
0.445948742,19470,142651,A-F,no,yes,no,yes,no,90 ,100 ,High,
0.759258355,93713,26669,CVA,no,no,no,no,no,68 ,40 ,Low,
```

Answer (score 0):

The parser is looking for a value after the last `,`.

To fix, simply remove those comma's at the end of each line (or maybe add a dummy column name at the end of the first line).